# Swift and Parse for messaging app?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, messaging

I'm relativily new to databases and Parse, but I'm trying to set up an app that can recieve and send messages between users. I've managed to set up the sign up and log in process, now I need to get the devices communicating.

Do anynone have any idea how to make this happen? I can imagine you'll have to create PFObjects with ID's and classes with some user-details so that only the two users communicating can send and retrieve messages to each other.

Any suggestions on how to set this up would be very appreciated.

Comment: how did you get on with using Parse with Swift?  Did it work? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure enough there are huge ways to setup communication between devices. But it totally depends on your communication needs.

For example, if you need "real time" communication,
like peer-2-peer, then you need to start looking for external service, such as PubNub, because you can't do that with Parse.

If you are trying to build some chat like app, then you can go with manually refreshing and
push notifications.

So, to do what you want you need to create message object and setup ACL for it

```
PFObject *groupMessage = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Message"];
PFACL *groupACL = [PFACL ACL];

// userList is an NSArray with the users we are sending this message to.
for (PFUser *user in userList) {
    [groupACL setReadAccess:YES forUser:user];
    [groupACL setWriteAccess:YES forUser:user];
}

groupMessage.ACL = groupACL;
[groupMessage saveInBackground];
```

So, here we've added ACL(access control list) rule for our message, to allow all users from userList access that message.

Also, don't forget to include additional information for message like 'recipient', 'sender' etc to be able to create queries using it. For example, to retrieve all messages send from concrete user.